# Passing application state between viewmodels in MVVM WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I need to write a small application to read a configuration file and generate some report with it. I was hoping to finally use MVVM but it's quite tricky to get started. Oh, I'm using Caliburn.Micro framework.

So this is what I have, a shell (primary view that hosts other views) that has a ribbon with 3 buttons on it:

1) Open file
2) Show settings
3) Show results

And two other views, SettingsView and ResultsView with buttons to generate and delete a report.

So I guess the view structure would be like this:

```
ShellView
   Ribbon
      OpenFileButton
      SettingsButton
      ResultsButton
   ContentControl (hosts SettingsView and ResultsView)

SettingsView
    CalculateResultsButton

ResultsView
    CancelResultsButton
```

The tricky part is this:

```
1. "Show settings" button is disabled until a file is opened (via Open file). 
2. "Show results" button is disabled until a report is calculated (via a 
    method in SettingsViewModel).
3. If a report is calculated, the CalculateResultsButton is disabled and
   CancelResultsButton is enabled and vice versa.
```

Please advise how could I achieve this ? I've no ideas what strategy should I go for. My non-MVVM-thinking-brain says that I should create a status variable and then somehow bind those buttons to that variable, but I guess that wont work in a MVVM world, right ? Any code example would be very very very appreciated!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using CM you won't need any code-behind.  You can delete the .xaml.cs files if you want.

This is a pretty basic example but it should give you an idea on how to control the state of the buttons.  In this example, `Open` will be enabled and the other two are disabled.  If you click on `Open`, `Settings` is enabled.  The same happens with `Results` once `Settings` is clicked.

If you need a way to do global state the same concept can be applied by injecting a singleton, `SharedViewModel`, into the ViewModels and the CanXXX methods can check values in `SharedViewModel`.  [This](https://bitbucket.org/dbeattie/cmdemo/src) is a SL demo of different things but one is injecting a singleton to share data, the same idea applies in wpf.

ShellView:

```
<Window x:Class="CMWPFGuardSample.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="Open"
                    Content="Open" />
            <Button x:Name="Settings"
                    Content="Settings" />
            <Button x:Name="Results"
                    Content="Results" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

ShellViewModel:

```
 [Export(typeof (IShell))]
    public class ShellViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IShell
    {
        private bool _isOpen;
        public bool IsOpen
        {
            get { return _isOpen; }
            set
            {
                _isOpen = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsOpen);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanSettings);
            }
        }

        private bool _isSettings;
        public bool IsSettings
        {
            get { return _isSettings; }
            set
            {
                _isSettings = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsSettings);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanResults);
            }
        }

        public bool IsResults { get; set; }

        public void Open()
        {
            IsOpen = true;
        }

        public bool CanSettings
        {
            get { return IsOpen; }
        }

        public void Settings()
        {
            IsSettings = true;
        }

        public bool CanResults
        {
            get { return IsSettings; }
        }

        public void Results()
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

MVVM and WPF Commands perfectly fits your "tricky part" requirements since have built in [ICommand.CanExecute()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336430.aspx) method which allows enabling/disabling corresponding button based on custom logic.

To use this naice feature take a look first at the [RoutedCommand Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.aspx) and self explanatory example on MSDN [How to: Enable a Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753200.aspx) (see below code snippets).

And in general about MVVM, it is really SIMPLE! Just try it and you won't leave without it ;) In few words - you have to create for each `EntityView.xaml` corresponding `EntityViewModel` class and then just put instance of it in the View's DataContext either explicitly in code or using bindings:

```
var entityViewModel = new EntityViewModel();
var view = new EntityView();
view.DataContext = entityViewModel;
```

MVVM Command and Command.CanExecute bindings:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WCSamples.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="CloseCommand"
    Name="RootWindow"
    >
  <Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"
                    Executed="CloseCommandHandler"
                    CanExecute="CanExecuteHandler"
                    />
  </Window.CommandBindings>
  <StackPanel Name="MainStackPanel">
    <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" 
            Content="Close File" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**C# code behind:**

```
// Create ui elements.
StackPanel CloseCmdStackPanel = new StackPanel();
Button CloseCmdButton = new Button();
CloseCmdStackPanel.Children.Add(CloseCmdButton);

// Set Button's properties.
CloseCmdButton.Content = "Close File";
CloseCmdButton.Command = ApplicationCommands.Close;

// Create the CommandBinding.
CommandBinding CloseCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(
    ApplicationCommands.Close, CloseCommandHandler, CanExecuteHandler);

// Add the CommandBinding to the root Window.
RootWindow.CommandBindings.Add(CloseCommandBinding);
```

Comment: Not ideal. Caliburn Micro avoids all the ICommand guff. http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/250844